# Mobile view affected by margins on paragraph tag

Tags: html, css

I set `margin-left/right:300px;` on a paragraph tag to push the edges of the containing header's background color to the text itself.

When I shrink the screen, the paragraph's background color eventually disappears, and the words move to the far right of the screen progressively until the words no longer exist.

Is there a better way to adjust the background color so it doesn't take up the entire allotted header space?

```css
#educationhead p {
    color: orangered;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
    background: rgba(54, 25, 25, .75);
    margin-left:300px;
    margin-right:300px;
}
```

```html
<header id="educationhead" class="section-header">
    <h2 class="section-title"><span>Education</span></h2>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <p id="edupara1" class="section-subtitle">Bla Bla Bla Text</p>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `display: table;` and `margin: 0 auto` on the `p` you can keep it centered. Other ways include setting `text-align: center;` on the parent or giving the `p` a specific width and doing `margin: 0 auto;`.

```css
#educationhead p {
    color: orangered;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
    background: rgba(54, 25, 25, .75);
    display: table;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<header id="educationhead" class="section-header">
    <h2 class="section-title"><span>Education</span></h2>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <p id="edupara1" class="section-subtitle">Bla Bla Bla Text</p>
</header>
```

Comment: Yes the paragraph text needs to be centered since I'm displaying a previous school I went to for my portfolio